# Python: Call method by instance object: "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"

Tags: python, class, methods, instance

I'm new to Python. I've written two Classes, the second one has an instance of the first one as a member variable. Now I want to call a method of Class2 via the instance of it in class one. I could not find an answer for it. Something like this:

```
class Class1:
    def uselessmethod(self):
        pass

class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.c = Class1()

    def call_uselessmethod(self):
        self.c.uselessmethod()

k = Class2
k.call_uselessmethod() # Error!
```

Gives the following error:

```
k.call_uselessmethod() #Error
TypeError: call_uselessmethod() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Any idea of what is going on here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`call_uselessmethod` requires that there first be an instance of `Class2` before you use it.  However, by doing this:

```
k = Class2
```

you are not assigning `k` to an instance of `Class2` but rather `Class2` itself.

To create an instance of `Class2`, add `()` after the class name:

```
k = Class2()
k.call_uselessmethod()
```

Now, your code will work because `k` points to an instance of `Class2` like it should.

Comment: Oh, thanks, I was blindfolded. Simply forgot the brackets...

Answer (score 2):

To create the instance, you need to *call* the class, `k = Class2()`.

What was really happening the that `k = Class2` created an alias to the class and k.call_uselessmethod`` created an unbound method which requires that you pass in the instance as the argument.

Here is a session that explains exactly what is happening:

```
>>> k = Class2      # create an alias the Class2
>>> k == Class2     # verify that *k* and *Class2* are the same
True
>>> k.call_uselessmethod   # create an unbound method
<unbound method Class2.call_uselessmethod>
>>> k.call_uselessmethod() # call the unbound method with the wrong arguments

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    k.call_uselessmethod() # call the unbound method with the wrong arguments
TypeError: unbound method call_uselessmethod() must be called with Class2 instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Note, the error message in Python2.7.6 has been improved over what you were seeing :-)

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
k = Class2
```

Is actually assigning the variable `k` to the *class* itself, which is a `type` object.  Remember, in Python *everything* is an object: classes are simply `type` objects.

```
>>> class Class2: pass
...
>>> k = Class2
>>> type(k)
>>> <class 'type'>
```

What you want is an *instance* of `Class2`.  For that you must call `Class2`'s constructor:

```
k = Class2()
```