# Type Error: Missing one positional argument "self" Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to attempt a small program that will simulate Conway's game of Life. However the error `TypeError: step() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` keeps on appearing. I have looked for a solution but nothing I try seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

class Cell (Button):
    Dead = 0
    Live = 1

    def __init__ (self,parent):
        Button.__init__(self,parent, relief = "raised" , width = 2 , borderwidth = 1 , command = self.onpress)
        self.displayState(Cell.Dead)

    def onpress (self):
        if self.state == Cell.Live:
            self.displayState(Cell.Dead)
        elif self.state == Cell.Dead:
            self.displayState(Cell.Live)

    def setNextState (self , Neighbours):
        if self.state == Cell.Live and (Neighbours < 2 or Neighbours > 3):
            self.nextState = Cell.Dead
        elif self.state == Cell.Dead and Neighbours == 3:
            self.nextState = Cell.Live
        elif self.state == Cell.Dead and Neighbours != 3:
            self.nextState = self.state

    def stepToNextState(self):
        self.displayState(self.nextState)

    def displayState (self , newstate):
        self.state = newstate
        if self.state == Cell.Live:
            self["bg"] = "black"
        if self.state == Cell.Dead:
            self["bg"] = "white"

class Grid:
    def __init__(self,parent,sizex,sizey):
        self.sizex = sizex
        self.sizey = sizey
        self.cells = []
        for a in range (0,self.sizex):
            rowcells = []
            for b in range (0, self.sizey):
                c = Cell(parent)
                c.grid(row=b , column=a)
                rowcells.append(c)
            self.cells.append(rowcells)

    def step (self):
        cells = self.cells
        for x in range (0,self.sizex):
            if x==0: x_down = self.sizex-1
            else: x_down = x-1
            if x==self.sizex-1: x_up = 0
            else: x_up = x+1
            for y in range(0,self.sizey):
                if y==0: y_down = self.sizey-1
                else: Y_down = y-1
                if y==self.sizey-1: y_up = 0
                else: y_up = y+1
                sum = cells[x_down][y].state + cells[x_up][y].state + cells[x][y_down].state + cells[x][y_up].state + cells[x_down][y_down].state +cells[x_up][y_up].state + cells[x_down][y_up].state + cells[x_up][y_down].state
            cells[x][y].setNextState(sum)
            for row in cells:
                for cell in row:
                    cell.stepToNextState()

    def clear(self):
        for row in self.cells:
            for cell in row:
                 cell.displayState(Cell.Dead)

def GridStep():
    Grid.step()

def GridClear():
    Grid.step()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.pack()
    grid = Grid(frame,25,25)
    bottomFrame = Frame(root)
    bottomFrame.pack (side = BOTTOM)
    buttonStep = Button(bottomFrame , text="Step" , command=GridStep)
    buttonStep.pack(side = LEFT)
    buttonClear = Button(bottomFrame, text = "Clear", command=GridClear)
    buttonClear.pack(side=LEFT , after=buttonStep)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm not a Pythonista, but it looks like `step` is an instance method; you're calling it on the class `Grid`.

Comment: please [edit] your question will the **full text** of the error, so we can see where it's occuring.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Call method by instance object: "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023986/python-call-method-by-instance-object-missing-1-required-positional-argument)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two functions that call *unbound methods*, directly on the class:

```
def GridStep():
    Grid.step()

def GridClear():
    Grid.step()
```

`Grid` is the class itself, not an instance of the class, and calling `Grid.step()` will not supply the `self` parameter as there is no instance to bind `self` *to*. You'll need to provide an instance of `Grid` here and call the method on *that*.

Instead of using `GridStep` and `GridClear` on your buttons, you'll need to pass the *methods* from the `grid` object you created:

```
grid = Grid(frame,25,25)
bottomFrame = Frame(root)
bottomFrame.pack (side = BOTTOM)
buttonStep = Button(bottomFrame , text="Step" , command=grid.step)
buttonStep.pack(side = LEFT)
buttonClear = Button(bottomFrame, text = "Clear", command=grid.clear)
buttonClear.pack(side=LEFT , after=buttonStep)
```

Note that I am passing in the bound methods to `command` but they are not (yet) called.

You can remove the `GridStep` and `GridClear` functions entirely then.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but now I get a new error when I try this saying that `AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'nextState'` in the stepToNext State Function Which I don't understand.

Comment: Your `Cell` instances do not have a `nextState` attribute until `setNextState` has been called, and even then only if certain conditions have been met. If you don't fully understand how this is supposed to work, perhaps best ask a *new* question though.