# Calling a class function from the same file in Python

Tags: python, function, class, self

How do I call a function defined in a class in Python?

```
       import pypyodbc as pyodbc

        Master_Conn = 'Driver={SQL Server};Server=server\23;Database=DBname;UID=username;PWD=password;'
        Master_db = pyodbc.connect(Master_Conn)
        Master_Cursor = Master_db.cursor()

        class Test:

            def __init__(self):
                self.master_status = ""


            def Getmodel(self):

                self.master_status= dict(Master_Cursor.execute("select col1,col2 from tablename ").fetchall())
                print (self.master_status)
Test.Getmodel()
```

With above code, I get

> **TypeError**: Getmodel() missing 1 required positional argument: *'self'*

So I tried `Test.Getmodel(self)` and it resulted in

> **NameError**: name *'self'* is not defined.

I even tried both scenarios with `if __name__== '__main__':` but got same errors.

Comment: .... is there some reason you are creating a class you aren't planning to instantiate? Use `test_object = Test() # instantiation` then you can call your *method* using `test_object.Getmodel()` But think about it: your function definition is `def Getmodel(self):`, it requires a `self`, why did you expect `Test.Getmodel()` to work without the argument?

Comment: You gotta instantiate that thing broseph

Comment: " I even tried both scenarios with if name== 'main':" that seems that you also don't understand what that is used for. As mentioned, you need to instantiate your class, but you might also want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Call method by instance object: "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023986/python-call-method-by-instance-object-missing-1-required-positional-argument)

Answer (score 2):

You are defining `Getmodel` as an **instance method**. So it have to be called on an instance of the class `Test`.

To create an instance of class `Test` you can write

```
instance_of_test = Test()
```

Now you can call `Getmodel` on `instance_of_test`

```
instance_of_test.Getmodel()
```

You can shorten this process by writing

```
Test().Getmodel()
```

Note that `self` is (usually) passed hiddenly when calling an instance method; it represents the instance calling the method.

---

Consider the following class `Pizza`

```
class Pizza:

    def __init__(self, size):
        self.size = size

    def get_size(self):
        return self.size
```

First you need to create an instance of `Pizza`

```
mypizza = Pizza(42)
```

then you can call the instance method `get_size` on `mypizza`

```
mypizza.get_size()
```

Answer (score 1):

What your doing will work if you instantiate an object of the class `Test` first. Instantiation just means you call the class as if it were a method which. The following should work:

`Test().Getmodel()`

The `()` is what makes the instantiation happen so now  the `self` essentially gets passed to the `Getmodel()` method because an object of the class `Test` now exists.